# provisioning bigquery datasets using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am new to GCP and Terraform. I am developing terraform scripts to provision around 50 BQ datasets and each datasets has minimum 10 tables. All the tables do not have same schema.

I have developed scripts to create datasets and tables, but I am facing challenge to add schemas to the tables and I need help. I am making use of terraform variables to build scripts.

Here is my code. I need to integrate logic to creates schemas for tables.

### var.tf

```
variable "test_bq_dataset" {
  type = list(object({
    id       = string
    location = string
  }))
}

variable "test_bq_table" {
  type = list(object({
    dataset_id = string
    table_id   = string
  }))
}
```

### terraform.tfvars

```
test_bq_dataset = [{
  id       = "ds1"
  location = "US"
  },
  {
    id       = "ds2"
    location = "US"
  }
]

test_bq_table = [{
  dataset_id = "ds1"
  table_id   = "table1"
  },
  {
    dataset_id = "ds2"
    table_id   = "table2"
  },
  {
    dataset_id = "ds1"
    table_id   = "table3"
  }
]
```

### main.tf

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "dataset" {
  count      = length(var.test_bq_dataset)
  dataset_id = var.test_bq_dataset[count.index]["id"]
  location   = var.test_bq_dataset[count.index]["location"]
  labels = {
    "environment" = "development"
  }
}


resource "google_bigquery_table" "table" {
  count = length(var.test_bq_table)
  dataset_id = var.test_bq_table[count.index]["dataset_id"]
  table_id   = var.test_bq_table[count.index]["table_id"]
  labels = {
    "environment" = "development"
  }
  depends_on = [
    google_bigquery_dataset.dataset,
  ]
}
```

I am tried all possibilities to create schemas for the tables in the datasets. However none worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably all your tables should have identical schema...

I would try this way

In the

`resource "google_bigquery_table" "table"`

just after labels, for example, you can add:

`schema = file("${path.root}/subdirectories-path/table_schema.json")`

where the

- `${path.root}` - is where you terraform file
- `subdirectories-path` - zero or many subdirectories
- `table_schema.json` - a json file with the schema

**==>** Update 14/02/2021

Following a request to show an example where table schemas are different... Minimum modifications from the original question.

**variables.tf**

```
variable "project_id" {
  description = "The target project"
  type        = string
  default     = "ishim-sample"
}

variable "region" {
  description = "The region where resources are created => europe-west2"
  type        = string
  default     = "europe-west2"
}

variable "zone" {
  description = "The zone in the europe-west region for resources"
  type        = string
  default     = "europe-west2-b"
}

# ===========================
variable "test_bq_dataset" {
  type = list(object({
    id       = string
    location = string
  }))
}

variable "test_bq_table" {
  type = list(object({
    dataset_id = string
    table_id   = string
    schema_id  = string
  }))
}
```

**terraform.tfvars**

```
test_bq_dataset = [
  {
    id       = "ds1"
    location = "EU"
  },
  {
    id       = "ds2"
    location = "EU"
  }
]

test_bq_table = [
  {
    dataset_id = "ds1"
    table_id   = "table1"
    schema_id  = "table-schema-01.json"
  },
  {
    dataset_id = "ds2"
    table_id   = "table2"
    schema_id  = "table-schema-02.json"
  },
  {
    dataset_id = "ds1"
    table_id   = "table3"
    schema_id  = "table-schema-03.json"
  },
  {
    dataset_id = "ds2"
    table_id   = "table4"
    schema_id  = "table-schema-04.json"
  }
]
```

An example of a json schema file - **table-schema-01.json**

```
[
  {
    "name": "table_column_01",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "type": "STRING",
    "description": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "_gcs_file_path",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "type": "STRING",
    "description": "The GCS path to the file for loading."
  },
  {
    "name": "_src_file_ts",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP",
    "description": "The source file modification timestamp."
  },
  {
    "name": "_src_file_name",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "type": "STRING",
    "description": "The file name of the source file."
  },
    {
    "name": "_firestore_doc_id",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "type": "STRING",
    "description": "The hash code (based on the file name and its content, so each file has a unique hash) used as a Firestore document id."
  },
  {
    "name": "_ingested_ts",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP",
    "description": "The timestamp when this record was processed during ingestion into the BigQuery table."
  }
]
```

**main.tf**

```
provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
  zone    = var.zone
}

resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "test_dataset_set" {
  project    = var.project_id
  count      = length(var.test_bq_dataset)
  dataset_id = var.test_bq_dataset[count.index]["id"]
  location   = var.test_bq_dataset[count.index]["location"]

  labels = {
    "environment" = "development"
  }
}

resource "google_bigquery_table" "test_table_set" {
  project    = var.project_id
  count      = length(var.test_bq_table)
  dataset_id = var.test_bq_table[count.index]["dataset_id"]
  table_id   = var.test_bq_table[count.index]["table_id"]
  schema     = file("${path.root}/bq-schema/${var.test_bq_table[count.index]["schema_id"]}")

  labels = {
    "environment" = "development"
  }
  depends_on = [
    google_bigquery_dataset.test_dataset_set,
  ]
}
```

**Project directory structure** - screenshot

[image]

Bear in mind the subdirectory name - "bq-schema" as it is used in the "schema" attribute of the "google_bigquery_table" resource in the "main.tf" file.

**BigQuery console** - screenshot

[image]

The result of the "terraform apply" command.

Comment: I must have add this to the question. Tables do not have identical schemas.

Comment: You probably can define a terraform variable - a map "table name => schema file name", or a list with the schema files names, so that the correct file is chosen using the same count loop instead of the const "table_schema.json".

Comment: could you please share an example using map.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform includes an optional [schema](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_table#schema) argument that expects a JSON string.

The documentation shared on the previous link has an example:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "default" {
  dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.default.dataset_id
  table_id   = "bar"

  time_partitioning {
    type = "DAY"
  }

  labels = {
    env = "default"
  }

  schema = <<EOF
[
  {
    "name": "permalink",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "The Permalink"
  },
  {
    "name": "state",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "State where the head office is located"
  }
]
EOF

}
```

Comment: I have 50 BQ Datasets and every DS has 10 tables and I do not prefer hardcoding values. Figuring out a way to make use of variables to create schema (Just like I have been doing to create tables and DS.)

Comment: I see! I didn't know the schemas where different. That'll definitely require another approach. I believe @al-dann 's answer offers a way better approach.